# package.xml structure for custom fields of standard objects

Tags: package.xml

I am having the below structure in Package.xml

```
<types>
       <members>*</members>
       <members>Account</members>       
      <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I am using this for copying Account standard object and all all custom objects from one sandbox to other.
Things are working fine, but I renamed some standard fields and also object label in "Account" object. Those are all copying properly but what ever fields names I used are not copying properly.

ie,

Account -- Provider

Can someone help with the proper Package.XML ?

Comment: The wildcard means you're pulling in _all_ SObjects (custom and standard). SObject fields are a separate metadata type `CustomField`. Is there a reason why you're using package.xml instead of SFDX or changesets?

Comment: @DerekF Incorrect. * CustomObject only pulls in custom objects, not standard objects.

Answer (score -1):

I achieved this by

```
<types>
     <members>*</members>
     <name>CustomLabel</name>
</types>
```